# In the file where I define a mixin class, how do I use the logger from the file where the mixin is used?

Tags: python, class, logging, mixins, superclass

I'm abstracting away a repetitive chunk of code where I set up a logger in many classes.

I'd like to have a class where a mixin allows me to either instantiate the class with a logger object, or use the default module in that class' module.

I'd use it like this:

````
import logging
from .mixin import LoggerMixin


resource_module_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyResource(LoggerMixin):
    """ Instantiate this class to do something.

    If instantiated with a custom logger, then all log outputs will go to that. Otherwise, they'll go to resource_module_logger

    ```
    MyResource().do_something()  # Does something while logging to resource module logger.
    MyResource(logger=logging.getLogger("specific"))  # does something while logging to a specific logger.
    ```
    """

    def do_something(self):
        self.logger.info("This message will go to the default module level logger, unless a custom logger was specified at instantiation")
````

The mixin I have so far is:

```
import logging


this_is_not_the_logger_im_looking_for = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class LoggerMixin:

    def __init__(self, *args, logger=None, **kwargs):

        self._logger = logger
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def logger(self):
        # How do I get the resource module logger for the MyResource class which this is mixed into???
        resource_module_logger = ?????????????
        return self._logger or resource_module_logger
```

**The Question**
Is it possible to get that logger from within the mixin, and therefore abstract this away fully (and if so, how?) or do I have to override the `logger` property for every class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than instantiating a global in the module and then trying to access it, you could just use `getLogger` directly to fetch the logger based on the module name. Also, I'd just do the defaulting once in `__init__` instead of on every lookup in the property:

```
self._logger = logger or logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__module__)
```

**Edit -- include complete solution**

The complete mixin, `loggable.py`, would then be:

````
import logging


class Loggable:
    """ Mixin to allow instantiation of a class with a logger, or by default use the module logger from that class

    ```
    class MyResource(Logged):
        def do_something(self):
            self.logger.info('write to a logger')

    MyResource().do_something()  # Log statements go to the default logger for the module in which MyResource is a member
    MyResource(logger=logging.getLogger("specific"))  # Log statements go to the specific logger.
    ```
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, logger=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._logger = logger or logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__module__)

    @property
    def logger(self):
        return self._logger
````